# What is the default target framework of VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How can i find the default target frame work of the VisualStudio 2017.
I need to create the csproj and solution file for VS2017 manually. 
The following screenshot shows the default target framework for VS2013.

[image]

Comment: Can any one have the sample csproj and sln files of VS2017RC. It will be helpful for me to construct the new project files from the existing one.

Comment: Hi All, I also need this information. Can anyone tell what will be default target framework for VS2017? 4.6 or 4.6.1 or 4.6.2

Comment: Hi All, I have installed the VS2017RC on my machine and have created the new windows forms application. It has been created with the default target frame work of 4.5.2 even though the highest supported framework is 4.6.2.

Comment: Doesn't it default to the last selection you've made?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default (when you create a new csproj in VS2017) the TargetFramework is set to **netstandard1.4**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would like to create the Visual C# application in Windows Forms platform. By default if i create the application in VS2013 the target framework will be 4.5.1. Is this the default frame work for VS2017 or 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed and checked with the VS2017. It has create the default project frame work as 4.5.2.

Regards,
Adhi